# Typeglob cannot be used under strict

Tags: perl

I understand how symbol and typeglob works, but I cannot understand when these would be used since typeglobs cannot be used under `use strict`.

Can someone please explain?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
#use strict;

$spud = 'wow';
@spud = qw(foo bar);
*potato = *spud;

print "$potato\n";
```

Edit: guys i am sorry.  I was in a hotel room and i typed up this question without thoughts and without verifying the code.   I see two errors.  One i didnt post the right code and also someone pointed out that my error checking was inaccurate.  I deserved all the negative vote as this was classic case of how one shouldnt ask questions.

Comment: Google search first entry returned [this](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=469971)

Comment: When you `use strict`, what error message do you get? Hint: this has *nothing* to do with typeglobs.

Comment: Your errors come from your variables not being declared with `my`

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking (since `use strict;` has no effects on typeglobs).

Comment: I am asking since all perl program should be programmed w/ use strict and when I declare *spud with use strict, it gives me error . *** actually I am wrong. I am able to declar but not sure how to use it yet.. will come back

Comment: @user3502374: Please answer the question, what error message do you get? I assure you that `use strict` has no effect on typeglobs.

Comment: I'm not clear how hotel rooms are supposed to degrade one's question-writing abilities!

Comment: We were hurry to leave the hotel to catch a uber but it is my fault that this post was pure definition of how not to ask questions! I will start a new thread once i can put my thoughts,examples and question in proper form. Apology once again

Answer (score 1):

The errors from your code are because you are using undeclared variables, and have nothing to do with typeglobs

If I simply declare all of the variables using `our` and reinstate `use strict`, your code works fine

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

our $spud = 'wow';
our @spud = qw(foo bar);

our ($potato, @potato);

*potato = *spud;

print "$potato\n";
print "@potato\n";
```

#### output

```
wow
foo bar
```

Typeglobs contain only *package* variables, so I have to use `our` instead of `my` to get this to work. Package variables should be avoided wherever possible, but different techniques are necessary for aliasing lexical variables

Aliasing is rarely necessary or useful, and it can easily make a labyrinth out of a simple piece of code. The one place where it is useful is in importing subroutines from another package (all named subroutines have package identifiers) but the core `Exporter` module implements the ugly guts of the importing process and should always be used unless you have an extraordinary requirement that `Exporter` cannot satisfy